# How to multiply one column by another in a csv file and re-write

Tags: python, csv, python-2.7, multiplication

I have some data in csv format and I need to perform a multiplication of the 3rd column by the 6th column and append the results to the end. My data is as follows:

```
 TITLE,TITLE,T,T,T,T
 data,data,5,data,data,98.7,data
 data,data,2,data,data,97,data
 data,data,5,data,data,98,data
 data,data,4,data,data,8.7,data
 data,data,5,data,data,9.7,data
 data,data,12.5,data,data,198.7,data
```

I am really new to coding, but my attempt was as follows:
    import csv
    import datetime
    import copy
    from collections import defaultdict

```
class_col = 2
data_col = 5

with open('minitest.csv', 'r') as f:
    data = [line.strip().split(',') for line in f]

for row in data:
    class_col*data_col

with open('minitest_edit.csv', 'w') as nf:
    nf.write('\n'.join(','.join(row) for row in data))

print "done"
```

I didn't get any errors come up, any suggestions? Thanks OS"

Comment: You should accept an answer—there are many good ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how one way to do it more efficiently, i.e. by not reading the data in memory, which will matter with larger data sets:

```
import csv
import tempfile
import shutil

input_file = 'minitest.csv'

with open(input_file, 'rb') as f, \
     tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as out_f:

    # in order to be able to not have to read everything in memory, we have to 
    # write every processed row to disk immediatley; for that, we need a temporary
    # file because we can't read and write a single file at the same time:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    writer = csv.writer(out_f)

    # header row
    writer.writerow(next(reader))

    # note that this uses a generator not a list, so that writerows will lazily
    # evaluate each row as it writes them to disk
    writer.writerows(row + [float(row[2]) * float(row[5])] for row in reader)

# one everything's done, overwrite the original file with the new contents.
shutil.move(out_f.name, input_file)
```

**P.S.** it would actually be simpler if you just didn't write back to the same file—you can always do the moving manually after the processing code has finished, to keep the processing code simpler.

Comment: accepted this answer because i really appreciate it when people put comments :)

Comment: @OliverSteph: I've just fixed some minor errors in the code, btw.

Answer (score 5):

Use `csv.reader` and `csv.writer`:

```
import csv


with open('minitest.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    data = [next(reader)]  # title row
    for row in reader:
        data.append(row + [float(row[2]) * float(row[5])])

with open('minitest.csv', 'wb') as nf:
    writer = csv.writer(nf)
    writer.writerows(data)
```

produces:

```
TITLE,TITLE,T,T,T,T
data,data,5,data,data,98.7,data,493.5
data,data,2,data,data,97,data,194.0
data,data,5,data,data,98,data,490.0
data,data,4,data,data,8.7,data,34.8
data,data,5,data,data,9.7,data,48.5
data,data,12.5,data,data,198.7,data,2483.75
```

Comment: CSV files should be opened and written with `rb` and `wb`. Also, the code could be made more efficient by doing the writing in the same loop as reading—this way you won't have to read everything in memory. If the problem is that you can't write to the file you're reading, you can just use `tempfile` and `mv`.

Answer (score 4):

You want the following to multiply your columns and append them to the original ones:

```
new_data = []
for row in data:
    new_data.append(row + [float(row[class_col]) * float(row[data_col])])
```

Comment: if `row` is a list, which I think it is, your code will throw a `TypeError` at runtime; additionally, it would be idiomatic to use a list comprehension instead of a for loop.

Comment: @ErikAllik Corrected that list concatenation error and cast strings to `float`

Answer (score 0):

If you are lucky and progamming on LUNIX you can use awk:

```
awk -F "\"*,\"*" '{print $0 "," $3*$6 }' test.csv > result.csv
```

And you can call it with Python http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html.